# dircopy and dirmove not working as expected

Tags: perl, filesystems, file-handling

I am writing a Perl script that allows us to easily move or copy a HUGE directory (possibly +100,000 subdirectories) to another location. I am using `File::Copy::Recursive` for this purpose like follows (incomplete! Some variables not defined, but it gives a minimal idea of what's going on):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy dirmove pathrmdir);
$File::Copy::Recursive::CPRFComp = 1;


my ($action, $source_location, $target_location) = @ARGV;
opendir(my $source_handle, $source_location) or die "Can't opendir $source_location: $!\n";
my $directories_found = 0;

while (my $sub_dir = readdir $source_handle) {
    unless (-d "$source_location/$sub_dir") {
        print STDERR "$source_location/$sub_dir not a dir\n";
        next;
    }
    # Makes sure we only move directories given a pattern defined elsewhere
    if ($sub_dir =~ $file_match_regex) {
        # $action is an input argument
        if ($action eq 'copy') {
            dircopy("$source_location/$sub_dir/", "$target_location/")
                or die "Cannot copy $source_location/$sub_dir/: $!\n";
        } elsif ($action eq 'move') {
            dirmove("$source_location/$sub_dir/", "$target_location/")
                or die "Cannot move $source_location/$sub_dir/: $!\n";
        }
        $directories_found = 1;
    } else {
        print STDERR "$source_location/$sub_dir did not match regex\n";
    }
}

if ($action eq 'move') {
    # Remove topmost directory
    pathrmdir($source_location)
        or die "Cannot remove $source_location: $!\n";
}

if (!$directories_found) {
    print STDERR "No items found to $action\n";
}
```

The first run this *seems to work as expected*. Take this command

```
perl myscript.pl move source/ /home/otherdir/target/
```

The terminal output is

```
source/. did not match regex
source/.. did not match regex
```

and that's it.

However, when I run the same script on the moved folder, things go wrong.

```
perl myscript.pl move /home/otherdir/target/ /home/failing/target/

/home/otherdir/target/. did not match regex
/home/otherdir/target/.. did not match regex
/home/otherdir/target/somefile1.txt not a dir
/home/otherdir/target/somefile2.txt not a dir
/home/otherdir/target/somefile3.txt a dir
/home/otherdir/target/somefile4.txt a dir
```

Obviously I shouldn't get different responses when running the same copy/move script on the data. It is peculiar, though, that the files come from one directory (I can't figure out which one they are all identical concerning content) and that the other directories are preserved. So in each run, for one $sub_dir the script copied the contents of the directory to the destination rather than the directory itself. This means that I am losing a directory on each run of the script... I don't understand why, though.

I think that I am misusing `dircopy` and `dirmove` , and I'm not sure if `$File::Copy::Recursive::CPRFComp = 1;` is correct either (I didn't found the documentation to be very clear for my novice eyes). Any thoughts?

---

After some more digging I think that this is what happens.The little documentation there is on CPRFComp reads (assuming 'foo/file'):

```
dircopy('foo', 'bar') or die $!;
# if bar does not exist the result is bar/file
# if bar does exist the result is bar/file

$File::Copy::Recursive::CPRFComp = 1;
dircopy('foo', 'bar') or die $!;
# if bar does not exist the result is bar/file
# if bar does exist the result is bar/foo/file
```

My guess is, thus, that The first copy/move action of a subdir is triggered before the target location ('bar' in the example) exists, which leads to bar/file rather than bar/foo/file. The question then changes to: how can I make sure that my copy/move operations wait until the target directory is build?

Comment: Your code shows you're printing `$source_location/$sub_dir did not match regex`, but your error message shows `. did not match regex`, missing the slash.  So you are either not showing your real code, or not showing your real output.  Please show your actual code and your actual error message, otherwise we have no way of knowing if the problems we find are your actual problems, or just the result of a faulty posting of your problem.

Comment: @PaulL I edited in an example. I do not quite understand why this gets downvoted though. If I need to provide more information, please tell me so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure that the path exist before any sub directories are moved or copied to it, I just create the path before doing the operation by using `make_path` of the File::Path module. Simply, like so:

```
if ($action eq 'copy') {
  make_path($target_location);
  dircopy("$source_location/$sub_dir/", "$target_location/")
        or die "Cannot copy $source_location/$sub_dir/: $!\n";
} elsif ($action eq 'move') {
  make_path($target_location);
  dirmove("$source_location/$sub_dir/", "$target_location/")
        or die "Cannot move $source_location/$sub_dir/: $!\n";
}
```